# svn access through terminal

Tags: svn, terminal

I am trying to access my svn from terminal using "svn co https://****" but it doesn't take my username and password:
It gives the below response for 3 times:
Authentication realm: https://******:443 Subversion Repositories

After 3 times it gives the below error:
authorization failed: Could not authenticate to server: rejected Basic challenge

I am using MAC terminal

Answer (score 0):

Start with `svn  --username NAME --password PASS ...` at least once - you probably have wrong authentication cached

Answer (score 0):

I have give the wrong user name and password. After I gave the correct ones it worked.